# Extraer una matriz JSON en filas en una consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json

Saludos Tengo una matriz JSON en una columna 25,35,75,98 etc y necesito pasarla a filas para poder sacar los Ids y poder normalizar haciendo INNER JOIN a otra tabla. Realizo la consulta a travez de este query

```sql
SELECT * , JSON_EXTRACT(work_workers,'$[*].id') AS workersId FROM work_orders
```

para poder extraer los ids que estan en la matriz multidimensional JSON me arroja:

```
["23,"254","586]
```

Luego de extraer los corchetes y comillas necesito que la cadena resultante:

```
23,254,586
```

poder pasarlo a filas debido a que necesito normalizar la tabla haciendo una consulta a otra con los ID a travez de INNER JOIN

Comment: Hola, considera agregar un poco de código y ser más específico en el problema para ayudarte

Comment: Considera editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de qué versión de MySQL estás usando. Dada una tabla como:

```
CREATE TABLE `work_orders` (
  `work_workers` json DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Y filas que contienen un array de IDs (vamos a decir que son de largo variable) del tipo:

```
INSERT INTO work_orders VALUES ('[{"id": "23"},{"id": "254"},{"id": "586"}]');
INSERT INTO work_orders VALUES ('[{"id": "12"},{"id": "180"}]');
INSERT INTO work_orders VALUES ('[{"id": "19"},{"id": "380"},{"id": "142"},{"id": "241"}]');
```

(La solución a continuación también la dejé en un **<kbd>[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2471df0d7a1629c01d2781d77bc538fa)</kbd>**)

**En MySQL 8.0 puedes usar [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)**

```
 SELECT wId, 
        work_workers
 FROM work_orders JOIN
   JSON_TABLE(
     work_workers,
     "$[*].id"
     COLUMNS(
       worker_id INT PATH "$"
     )
   ) tbl ON 1=1

| wId |                     work_workers                     |
|-----|------------------------------------------------------|
|  23 | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
| 254 | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
| 586 | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
|  12 | [{"id": "12"}, {"id": "180"}]                        |
| 180 | [{"id": "12"}, {"id": "180"}]                        |
|   9 | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   3 | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   4 | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   6 | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
```

En MySQL 5.7 lamentablemente tienes que generar tantas filas como puedas necesitar. En este caso, como el largo es variable, tendrías que generar una cantidad igual al largo máximo y añadir una cláusula para no traer índices inexistentes:

```
SELECT pos,
  JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_EXTRACT(work_workers, CONCAT( '$[',pos,'].id')
  ) AS wId,
  work_workers
FROM work_orders JOIN
(
   SELECT 0 as pos 
   UNION 
   SELECT 1 
   UNION 
   SELECT 2 
   UNION 
   SELECT 3
   UNION 
   SELECT 4 
) tbl ON (pos)<JSON_LENGTH(work_workers)
```

Además, si vas a usar `wId` para hacer un join, puede que sea mejor idea castearlos como número.

```
 SELECT pos,
   CAST(
     JSON_EXTRACT(work_workers, CONCAT( '$[',pos,'].id')
   ) AS UNSIGNED) wId,
   work_workers
 FROM ...
```

Estoy usando el "generador de filas" para obtener en cada fila (1..i..N) el iésimo elemento del array que lo acompaña.

Esto entrega:

```
| pos | wId |                     work_workers                     |
|-----|-----|------------------------------------------------------|
|   0 | 23  | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
|   0 | 12  | [{"id": "12"}, {"id": "180"}]                        |
|   0 | 9   | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   1 | 254 | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
|   1 | 180 | [{"id": "12"}, {"id": "180"}]                        |
|   1 | 3   | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   2 | 586 | [{"id": "23"}, {"id": "254"}, {"id": "586"}]         |
|   2 | 4   | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
|   3 | 6   | [{"id": "9"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}, {"id": "6"}] |
```